# Issues with KeyError: 'val_acc'

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

This is rather a popular error, but I couldn't find a proper answer given my setup.
I found this tutorial code, but when running, I get this error:

```
val_acc = history.history['val_acc'] 
KeyError: 'val_acc'
```

The `fit_generator()` function unlike `fit()`, doesn't allow a validation split. So how to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
def plot_training(history):
    print (history.history.keys())
    acc = history.history['acc']
    val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
    loss = history.history['loss']
    val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
    epochs = range(len(acc))

    plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'r.')
    plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r')
    plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')

    # plt.figure()
    # plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'r.')
    # plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r-')
    # plt.title('Training and validation loss')
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('acc_vs_epochs.png')
#....
finetune_model = build_finetune_model(base_model, dropout=dropout, fc_layers=FC_LAYERS, num_classes=len(class_list))
adam = Adam(lr=0.00001)
finetune_model.compile(adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
filepath="./checkpoints/" + "ResNet50" + "_model_weights.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor=["acc"], verbose=1, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

history = finetune_model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, workers=8, 
                                       steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
                                       shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list)

plot_training(history)
```

Comment: You didn't provide any validation data to fit_generator, so of course no validation metrics (the ones starting with val_) are available.

Comment: Of course. And hence my question how to add it, e.g. 20% of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi writting my suggestions here because I'm not able to comment yet,

You are right the fuction `fit_generator()` dosen't have the validation split attribute. 
Therefore you need to make your own validation dataset and feed it to the fit generator through `validation_data=(val_X, val_y)` as eg.:

```
history = finetune_model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, workers=8, validation_data=(val_X, val_y),
                                   steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
                                   shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

To get a validation dataset from your data you can use the methode `train_test_split()` from sklearn. For example a split with 77% train and 33% validation data:

```
X_train, val_X, y_train, val_y= train_test_split(
X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Look [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for more information.

Alternatively you could write your own split methode :)

**Edit 2**

If you don't have the possibility to use train_test split and with the assumption you have a pandas dataframe called `train_data` with the features and labels together:

```
val_data=train_data.sample(frac=0.33,random_state=1)
```

This should creates a validation dataset with 33% of the data and a train dataset with 77% of the data.

**Edit3**

It turns out you are using `ImageDataGenerator()` to create your data. This is quite handy because you can set your validation percentage via `validation_split=` while you initialize the ImageDataGenerator() as seen in the documentation ([here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)). This should look something like this:

```
train_datagen =   ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
    validation_split=0.33)
```

After this you need two "generated" datasets. One to train and one to make your validation. This should look as following:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_DIR,
target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH),
batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,subset="training")

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_DIR,
target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH),
batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,subset="validation")
```

Finally you can use both sets in your fit_generator as following:

```
history = finetune_model.fit_generator(train_generator,epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, workers=8, 
validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps = validation_generator.samples,steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Let me know if this solves your problem :)

Comment: Thanks. But question is how to make the validation set available via a percentage? e.g. reserve 20% of data for validation.

Comment: Hi, you could just use the train_test_split() methode from sklearn will put example in answer.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't have `X` and `Y` in my code to split them. Can you please share an approach according to my code?

Comment: Just for completion: X are the features of your Data and y are the labels.
With the assumption that your data is stored in "train_generator" and it is a pandas dataframe and without knowing how your data looks i have another solution in Edit2. 
If this doesn't help we should maybe talk how your data looks and what you load into "train_generator" :)

Comment: Thanks. Still no EDIT2!

Comment: Should be up now ^^

Comment: Thanks. So in my code, your `train_data` is train_generator or train_datagen?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201856/discussion-between-fabian-and-tina-j).

Comment: if I want to change my multi-class training to only binary, what should I change? I changed it to `finetune_model.compile(adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`, but I get an error saying `KeyError: 'acc'`!